# Laravel 5.4 show activation pending message on login form

Tags: laravel-5, authentication

I am working on Laravel 5.4 project. I love the login provided by Laravel and it works fine with both login or register.

I add below code to Auth/LoginController.php. It allows only activated users (status=1) to successfully login, but not pending users or blocked users (status =0 or something else).

```
protected function credentials(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    return ['email' => $request->{$this->username()}, 'password' => $request->password, 'status' => 1];
}
```

Anyway, to protect spam I would like to allow only activated users to login. For those whose account are not activated, I would like to show the pending message on the login form. Also, I would like to do the same thing for blocked users.

Could you please advise me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way Laravel would only pick only users by the credentials you specify, if you want to check status the user has and what view to show you can overwrite the `authenticated()` method of the login controller. It will have access to the already logged in user so note that you have to logout it the status is invalid.

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ( $user->status == 0 ) {
        auth()->logout();

        return back()->withErrors(['email' => 'You are blocked or not activated.']);
    }

    return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Where in login controller should I place this code correctly. After adding this, It gives me error Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::authenticated() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, instance of Illuminate\Http\Request given....

Comment: @Udom you have to import the class to your controller. Add `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top of your file after the namespace declaration.

Comment: That works great! Anyway, could you tell me how to give message that the email is not registered yet?